# Server/Client. The Client uses a lot of memory

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

This is my first question and I hope you can help me.

I have 2 programs, a Server and a Client and my problem is in the Client.

After 2 or 3 days of running, it uses more than 300MB of RAM (I can tell this by seeing the TaskManager) and never releases it! Also, I have to say that this Client receives data every second from GPS devices.
I have analyzed my Client with the ANTS Memory Profiler and I noticed that I create an object several times and they are never destroyed.

Here is my code:

```
private static TcpClient _client;
private readonly ManualResetEvent _receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public void Receive()
{
    if (_client.Connected)
    {
        _receiveDone.Reset();
        ObjectState state = new ObjectState(); 
        state.WorkSocket = _client.Client;
        state.Data = new byte[_client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        _client.Client.BeginReceive(state.Data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_client.ReceiveBufferSize), 0, ReceiveCallback, state);

        if (!_receiveDone.WaitOne(20000)) 
        {
            //after 20 seconds WITHOUT RECEIVING DATA, do some code to test if the connection is alive                        
        }
    }
}

void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    ObjectState state = (ObjectState)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket client = state.WorkSocket;
    if (client.Connected)
    {
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Data, 0, bytesRead);
            doProcess(response);
            client.BeginReceive(state.Data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_client.ReceiveBufferSize), 0, ReceiveCallback, state);
            _receiveDone.Set();
        }
        else
        {
        //Disconnection
        }
    }
}

public class ObjectState
{
    public Socket WorkSocket;
    public byte[] Data;
}
```

The ANTS Memory Profiler tells me I have thousands of live instances of `byte[]`. (because I always create new instances of `ObjectState`)

First thing I wanted to do: Dispose all the `ObjectState` that I create after I call `BeginReceive`, but I only get the first message.

Then I wanted to stop using the `ObjectState`... How?
This is my modified code:

```
private _data byte[];

public void Receive()
{
    if (_client.Connected)
    {
        _receiveDone.Reset();
        _data = new byte[_client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        _client.Client.BeginReceive(_data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_client.ReceiveBufferSize), 0, ReceiveCallback, null);

        if (!_receiveDone.WaitOne(20000)) 
        {
            //after 20 seconds of inactivity do some code to test if the connectio is alive                        
        }
    }
}

void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket client = _cliente.Client;
    if (client.Connected)
    {
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_data, 0, bytesRead);
            doProcess(response);
            client.BeginReceive(_data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_client.ReceiveBufferSize), 0, ReceiveCallback, null);
            _receiveDone.Set();
        }
        else
        {
            //Disconnection
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this? I only get the first message, so this is not good.
Then if I remove the `_receiveDone.Set` it gets all the messages, BUT the `_receiveDone.WaitOne(2000)` always is executed every 20 seconds, no matter if I actually am receiving data, and this is not good either.

So my question is, what can I do to reduce the using of so much RAM? I hope this explains well what my problem is.

**EDIT:**
I uploaded these images, I hope they can be helpful too.
[image: Summary]
[image: Instant Retention Graph]

Comment: Can you post the instance retention graph of ANTS Memory Profiler?

Comment: OK, I'll make it run for a couple of hours and then upload and image... thanks

Comment: Dont let it run for long. Make a snapshot, receive a 1 or 2  messages and make a second snapshot.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your last comment. I uploaded the snapshot after running almost a day. As you can see, the `Byte[]` class gets a lot of memory RAM that is never released. Hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (client.Connected)
{
    int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
    // etc..
```

Calling EndReceive is *not* optional, you *have* to call it or you'll leak resources.  Use try/catch to catch an ObjectDisposedException.

Comment: Good catch. That's not the entire problem, but likely a big part of it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I forgot to say that I use try/catch but I didn't want to write it in order to make the post smaller.

Comment: *Never* edit your code when you have subtle problems like this.  I'm guessing my answer is still accurate.

Comment: Yes I know it could be very critical, but I have to do something in order to fix it. About your answer, I think I'm already doing that. I mean, I'm using "EndReceive" and a "try/catch" block. I didn't write the last one, but I'm really using it. Also, I haven't gotten an Exepction like the one you told me.

Comment: You are seriously missing the point of the answer.  Delete that if() statement.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't understand. I'll remove that and see what happens :)

Comment: Well, the problem wasn't solved but it's true I shouldn't have that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the primary problem is that you're depending on `BeginReceive` to return 0 bytes when there's nothing available. But that's not how it works. `BeginReceive` will block until there is data available, or until the client disconnects.

In the first case, the `ReceiveCallback` passes the `state` object to `client.BeginReceive`. Now you have an `ObjectState` instance out there waiting for data from the client. The `_receiveDone` event is set, so your `Receive` method exits but the client connection is still open and you have a pending asynchronous read.

The next time `Receive` is called, it will create *another* `ObjectState` instance and issue another asynchronous read request.

The second case is pretty scary. Your `_data` array is at class scope and gets reallocated every time. So it's possible that an asynchronous read can fill the buffer you pass it, but then the data is lost when you get to `ReceiveCallback`.

Your code only does the timeout check for the first receive. After that, things can hang indefinitely. I would suggest something more like:

```
private _data byte[];
private bool _receiving = false;

public void StartReceiving()
{
    if (_receiving)
    {
        // ERROR: Already receiving
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    _receiving = true;
    Receive();
}

public void Receive()
{
    if (_client.Connected)
    {
        _data = new byte[_client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        var ir _client.Client.BeginReceive(_data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_client.ReceiveBufferSize), 0, ReceiveCallback, null);

        if (!_ir.WaitOne(20000)) 
        {
            //after 20 seconds of inactivity do some code to test if the connectio is alive                        
        }
    }
}

void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket client = _cliente.Client;
    int bytesRead;
    try
    {
        bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_data, 0, bytesRead);
            doProcess(response);
            // Calling Receive here ensures that the timeout check happens
            // with every read.
            Receive();
        }
        else
        {
            _receiving = false;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Catch SocketException and others here
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need the `_receiveDone` event. You can check it with the `IAsyncResult.WaitHandle`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestion. But before I do it... With this, will I be able to get the "waitDone" working properly? Because I really need it. I have some processes that HAVE to be executed only after 20 seconds without receiveing data, not always after 20 seconds.

Comment: @gabriel: Yes. If this doesn't receive any data within 20 seconds, then the `_ir.WaitOne` will fail and you can execute whatever code you need to.

Comment: I tried with that but it didn't work, just to be sure... my "if" statement should be like this: `if (!ir.AsyncWaitHandle .WaitOne(20000))`, right?

Comment: @gabriel: yes. If it's not working, I would suggest that you put in some tracing code that tells you what's going on.

Comment: OK, now I'm seeing for a different solution. If the new one fails I'll keep trying with these things you recommended me, thank you.